# pin (position fixed) row or column in flutter , renderflex expected a child of type renderbox but received a child of type _RenderSliverPinnedPersiste

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this row which I use for filtering and stuff like that, It has been many weeks that I am searching and trying to find a solution to pin or let's say fixed when user scrolls to bottom, so the row is kind of at the center of the application in home screen, is there anyway to pin a custom widget like row, column...etc!, thanks in advance.
basically, I have a row in the center of the screen, it is containing button with icons, I want the user when scrolls to bottom to be pinned at the top always.

here is the code:

```
SliverAppBar(
    pinned: true,
        title: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {  },
                          
                          label: Text("all".tr, style: robotoRegular.copyWith(color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.grey[800])),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.all_inclusive,color: Colors.teal,),
                          )
                    ),    Container(
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {
                         
                          },
                       
                          label: Text("cheapest_price".tr, style: robotoRegular.copyWith(color:Colors.grey,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.price_change_outlined,color: Colors.green,),
                          )
                    ),    Container(
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {
                         
                          },
                         
                          label: Text("most_expensive".tr, style: robotoRegular.copyWith(color: Colors.grey,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.price_change,color: Colors.orange,),
                          )
                    ), 
                   
                  ],
                ),
          ),
      )
```

error: renderflex expected a child of type renderbox but received a child of type _RenderSliverPinnedPersistentHeaderForWidgets.

Comment: it's hard to say what you really want to achieve, maybe post some images with the desired result

Comment: hi @pskink, basically, I have a row in the center of the screen, it is containing button with icons, I want the user when scrolls to bottom to be pinned at the top always.

Comment: try [SliverPersistentHeader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html)